# Mongoose and Express: Find always return a null

Tags: javascript, mongodb, node.js, express, mongoose

I always get a null returned for result in any find(), anywhere in my code. It all used to work last week. My database is running properly. Here is a sample:

```
var getParcourList = function(userId, callback){

   GeneralReference.findOne({ id: userId}, function(err, result){
    var callB;
     if(err || result === null){
       console.log("error in save: " + err + " - User returned for " + userId + " : " + result);
       callB = "No Document found: " + err; 
     }else{
       console.log(userId + " : " + result);
       callB = result.parcours; 
     } 
     callback(callB);
  });

}
```

Comment: What does the findOne function do?

Comment: Not a ton to go on here - what has changed since last week? Did you upgrade any drivers, frameworks, db version, etc?

Does the same query work in the mongodb console?

Comment: You may want a better title and to actually mention you're using MongoDB in your question. It's only in your tags that you indicate what you're using!

Comment: It is a database issue. My removed every collection, and restarted my app and started repopulating data and everything worked... Seems to be related to when my database is shutdown and restarted, It cant find the id anymore... any clues?